# How to Subscribe Observable in different Child component in Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have component `parent` and two child `A` and `B` component.
I created a `Observable` in `parent` and subscribe in `A` by passing though `@input` in `A`.

On change on `parent` `A` function get calls through subscription.

But i want to change the `B` also.
i have checked [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39627396/angular-2-observable-with-multiple-subscribers)

I want to get the change of `parent` model in all the `childrens`

Comment: try looking into multicasting: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/multicast.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved :

```
 let c: Observable<Array<WorkFlow>> = Observable.create((obs: Observer<Array<WorkFlow>>) => {
            this._wfService.getWorkFlows(0, 50).subscribe((data: Array<WorkFlow>) => {
                this.workFlows = data;
                obs.next(this.workFlows);
            }, (err: Response) => {
                console.error(err);
            });
        });
this.workFlowsOb = c.shareReplay(1);
```

I was returning the `c` before , now i used `c.shareReplay` and share to Observable that is shared to all children components