# Angular multiple http.get requests

Tags: angular, angular-http, angular-observable

How can I make only one http request but subscribe multiple times to the service?

The documentation states that they are called multiple times:

```
const req = http.get<Heroes>('/api/heroes');
// 0 requests made - .subscribe() not called.
req.subscribe();
// 1 request made.
req.subscribe();
// 2 requests made.
```

Source: https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-delete-request (a bit down).

Is there a way, that the http request is done only once?

Background: I'm making a service which checks if the requests are identically, and if yes, it returns the last `observable`. Now if the requests are made twice this "optimization" becomes obsolete.

All related answers are to Angular

Comment: Subscribe once on your request and store the output in some variable of type Observable and subscribe to that variable instead of http request again.

Comment: @eduPeeth how to best create such a observable? https://angular.io/guide/observables looks pretty complex

Comment: what's the type of Heroes here? looks like array of  hero?

Comment: Does that help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39627396/angular-2-observable-with-multiple-subscribers

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments I solved it like this:

```
this.lastObservable = new Observable(observe => {
        this.http.get(url).subscribe(
          result => {
            // observable execution
            observe.next(result)
          },
          error => {
            observe.error(error)
          },
          () => {
            observe.complete();
          }
        );
```