# Massive component subcriptions or single subscription + export data?

Tags: angular, performance

I'm starting with Angular and I'm having some design questions about what's the **best way of doing things in terms of reliability and performance**.

I have a SettingsService that fetch some user settings from the BackEnd Server and I wan't to publish/emit those settings into a lot of Components using **Observables**.

I've found  **2 options** but I don't know what's the best solution:

1) **Subscribing each component to SettingsService** (I've got like 15 components that needs that settings data so It will add a LOT of code)

2) **[What is shown on below's diagram] Subscribing 1 Service (Service A) to SettingsService and export that data to be consumed by each of those 15 Components**, so I write less code and do a single subcription. (**Thing is I don't know if that variable from Service A is persistent**, I mean, If Component N have an instance of Service A (with a certain 'snapshot' scope) and suddenly some variable changes, will it keep persistent? Is this option a **good practice?**)

I tried to be as clear as posible, sorry If I did some 'newbie' mistake.

Thank you a lot!!!

[image: diagramm]

Comment: Option 1 should work fine if use BehaviorSubject: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39627396/angular-2-observable-with-multiple-subscribers . I'm not 100% sure how you want to do this with option 2 cause this should be the same as option 1 if you use BehaviorSubject. In the end I think option 2 will consume to much time and will be more error heavy.
If you talk about performance it should be equal.

Comment: Hi @Swoox, thanks for answering. I'm actually doing it with BehaviorSubject, I know the code I have to write but I don't know the "perspective" of doing things with option 1 or 2.

Comment: I think you overthink it to much and just go with option 1 and start programming. (personal opinion)

Comment: Haha, that's true. Just started with Angular and I'm so afraid of doing wrong/bad practices/low performance code :P

Comment: In my opinion option 2 is not bad but more error heavy. Cause at some point you will need to control the data going to some component and not all components.

Comment: well, theoretically I could do that just importing the variable from Service A inside the Component. I think I'm going for option 1. :)